# HTML5 two forms to be printed out separately

Tags: javascript, html

So i am working on a project that has one page for convenience, there is two forms on the page.

Now i have tried a few things and they don't seem to work for me.
What i need to do is have the Sales person form print out and then print the Customers section afterwords.

Is their a way to achieve this with JavaScript or better if i can do this directly in HTML5.

Comment: Give more information about your page. Some codes etc.

Comment: Its quit simple i have two forms as such below. <div class="Customer">   <feildset></fieldset></div> <div class="Sales"><fieldset></fieldset></div>   Thats what it looks like bu ti need to print each section separably based on the class.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have an idea, Open a new pop-up window with content Customer div, and print it out. When window's closed *-check with an infinite loop with 'a timer'-*, open up another pop-up window with content Sales div this time and print it out, too.

Comment: sorry, i have written anything but C# for a long while...any examples of what your trying to explain to me?

Comment: You can search for it, I think. And there is no C# I can see. This is all about javascript.

Comment: okay. So what your saying is when the button print is pushed it should open up a windows will the customers copy and print it, then when closed print the sales copy.

Comment: Yes it's exactly what I said. There is no way I can see now.